# How to properly use a Interface from a external DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, interface

I have the following problem:

I have an external DLL that communicates with a software. I have already added in the references menu in Visual Studio 2015 and all I can do from the reference is to create a **interface** that allows me to access the DLL methods.

Here's MY code:

```
using SystemMonitor;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SystemMonitor.ITSysMonApiDual API;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        public void apriprj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            API.CloseProject();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button apriprj_Click I have the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have an example of how to do it in C++ from the manual:

```
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Mclaren Electronic Systems\\System Monitor V7\\SystemMonitor.tlb" rename("SendMessage", "SmSendMessage") named_guids




HRESULT hr = S_OK;

SystemMonitor::ITSysMonApiDualPtr pSmApi;    

hr = pSmApi.CreateInstance(SystemMonitor::CLSID_TSysMonApi);
```

How can I implement this code in C# ?
Or how can I instance the "interface" in C# ?

Comment: API = new SystemMonitor.ITSysMonApiDual();  Kinda obvious, isn't it?  C# is an obvious language, very unlike C++.

Comment: @Hans Passant Actually you are wrong because if ITSysMonApiDual is an interface you cannot create an instance from it.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  Luckily the C# designers were not wrong and allowed the syntax.  The compiler looks for the [CoClassAttribute] on the interface to know how create the object.  Which is how C# became an obvious language.